# Basic scala - second degree polynomial

Tags: scala

Could someone help me with the following question? I'm relatively new to Scala and my lecturer didn't supply us with any exam paper answers so need to know a correct way to do certain questions.

---

Using the Scala syntax, write a function for the second degree polynomial. Second degree polynomial is of form:

y=ax^2+bx+c

Your function should be named second and it should take 4 parameters: a, b, c and x. Parameters should accept real numbers and a real number should be returned. Also, write an anonymous version of this function using the Scala syntax.

Comment: "my lecturer didn't supply us with any exam paper answers" As excuses go, that's pretty feeble. It's a very basic question - at least have a go and when you are stuck, post  a specific question.  The question is very  clear - you can at least attempt to get the parameters defined, return value and so on.

Answer (score 0):

These pages should help you learn the basics of function declarations:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_functions.htm
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/anonymous_functions.htm